# Is this special case of the subset-product problem $\mathsf{NP}$-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

It is a well known fact that the following 'subset-product' problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete when $n/\log M \in \Theta(1)$.

> Consider a size-$n$ subset of a multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}\cong\mathbb{Z}^{*}_M$. Then an instance of the subset-product problem consists of $(a_1, a_2,\dots,a_n, t)$ with each $a_i, t\in \mathbb{G}$ and the problem asks to find a (possibly $s(n)$-size, where $s(n)\in\Theta(n)$) subset $S\subset[n]$ such that $\prod_{i\in S}a_i = t$.

Is the special case where $t=1$ also $\mathsf{NP}$-complete? In particular, can every instance of the subset-product problem be reduced to an instance where one needs to find a subset whose product is $1_{\mathbb{G}}$?

Since the fact is true for the related subset-sum problem (that every general subset-sum instance can be reduced to one in which the goal is to find a subset which sums to $0$) it could possibly be true. Are there any known results which deal with the above? References would be appreciated.

Comment: SUBSET SUM is NP-complete even when the target is $0$. If $M$ is a large prime and we know a primitive root modulo $M$, or at least an element with large order, then we can reduce SUBSET SUM to your problem with the given $M$, assuming $M$ is large enough (larger than the sum of absolute values of the input subset). This shows that your problem is NP-hard with respect to randomized reductions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your problem is NP-complete, even when we restrict to the case where $t=1$.

We will focus on the case $M=2^k$.  Then $\mathbb{Z}_M^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}^{2^{k-2}}$, and $3$ has order $2^{k-2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_M^*$, so the subgroup generated by $3$ modulo $M$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{2^{k-2}}$.  (See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2460124/14578.)

This lets us reduce the ordinary [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) to your problem.  Suppose we have an instance of (positive) subset sum, namely, $x_1,\dots,x_n \ge 0$ and a target $y$; the question is whether there exists a subset of the $x_i$'s that sum to $y$. Choose $k$ large enough that $2^{k-2} \ge x_1 + \dots + x_n$, and set $M=2^k$.  Let $a_i = 3^{x_i} \bmod M$, $a_{n+1} = 3^{-y} \bmod M$, and $t=1$.  Then there is a solution to your problem (with values $a_1,\dots,a_{n+1}$ and target $t=1$) iff there is a solution to the original subset sum instance.  This shows how to reduce the (positive) subset sum problem to your problem with $t=1$, which proves that your problem is NP-complete.

My thanks to Yuval Filmus for [the main ideas underlying this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/152247/is-this-special-case-of-the-subset-product-problem-mathsfnp-complete#comment320262_152247).

---

This doesn't prove that your problem is hard for all $M$.  There may well be choices of $M$ where the problem is easy.  In particular, for the special case where $M=3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times \cdots \times p$ is the product of the first few primes, I'm not sure whether the problem remains NP-complete or not.  (Why do I have some doubts?  Well, the subset sum problem is not hard over $\mathbb{Z}_2^k$: it can be solved in polynomial time with linear algebra.  When $M=3 \times \cdots \times p$, then $\mathbb{Z}_M^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6 \times \cdots \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$, and the isomorphism can be efficiently computed in both directions using the Chinese remainder theorem.  So when $M$ has this special form, the situation feels somehow close to the case of $\mathbb{Z}_2^k$, and I'm not sure whether there might some sophisticated generalization of linear algebra that can be used to solve the subset sum problem over $\mathbb{Z}_M^*$ efficiently or not.)